# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException in selenium web driver with sauce lab connection

Tags: selenium

```
public class SelectSurveyPageTest extends TestBase {

SelectSurveyPage sp;    LoginPage lp;   WeightOfPatientQue weightOfPatient ;

public SelectSurveyPageTest() throws InvocationTargetException      {       super();    }

@Test(priority=1)   public void loginValid() throws InterruptedException    {       String str2=sp.loginValidation();       System.out.println(str2);   }       @Test(priority=2)   public void surveySelection() throws InterruptedException   {       //String str2=sp.loginValidation();         weightOfPatient=sp.surveySelection();           }       @BeforeMethod   public void surverySetUp() throws Exception     {       initialization();       lp=new LoginPage();         sp=lp.loginPageTest1();
            }       @AfterMethod    public void surveyTearDown()    {       driver.quit();  } }
```

Test Base class

```
public class TestBase {         public static WebDriver driver;     public static Properties prop;  public static String configfilepath;
         private static String ID = null;

        public static final String USERNAME = System.getenv("SAUCE_USERNAME");  public static final String ACCESS_KEY = System.getenv("SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY");  //public static  String user=prop.getProperty("SAUCE_USERNAME");
    //public static  String access_key=prop.getProperty("SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY");
    //public static String url_last=prop.getProperty("Sauce_url_last");     public static final String URL = "http://" + USERNAME + ":" + ACCESS_KEY + "@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub" ;
    //String Sauce_brows=prop.getProperty("Sauce_browser");     protected String sessionId;
    String baseURL=prop.getProperty("baseurl");     long pageload_time = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("Page_load_Time"));  long implicit_time = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("Implicit_Time"));

        public TestBase() throws InvocationTargetException  {
                try         {
            prop=new Properties();
            FileInputStream fi=new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Dynamisch Lap\\eclipse-workspace\\PeerTest_Maven\\src\\main\\java\\com\\config\\config.properties");
            //InputStream fi = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
            prop.load(fi);      }
                catch (IOException e)       {           e.printStackTrace();        }
            }       public void initialization() throws MalformedURLException   {        DesiredCapabilities caps =  DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
             caps.setCapability("platform", "Windows 7");
             caps.setCapability("version", "60.0");
             caps.setCapability("recordVideo", "false");
             caps.setCapability("screenResolution", "1280x960");
             caps.setCapability("name", "Peer Test");



            driver=(new RemoteWebDriver(new java.net.URL(URL),caps));

            this.sessionId = (((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getSessionId()).toString();

            driver.get(baseURL);            driver.manage().window().maximize();            driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(pageload_time, TimeUnit.SECONDS);            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(implicit_time, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }
```

Console

> ---
>
> ```
> [RemoteTestNG] revisions:
>   git.commit.id=f7160ab
>   git.branch=f7160ab041ae763e01e10b6867b5d40d49e2688e
>   git.build.version=1.3.1
> [RemoteTestNG] loaded class org.testng.internal.Version at file:/C:/Users/Dynamisch%20Lap/.p2/pool/plugins/org.testng_6.14.2.r201802161450.jar
> [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2
> [RemoteTestNG] Invoked with -serport 53913 -protocol json -d
> ```

C:\Users\Dynamisch Lap\eclipse-workspace\PeerTest_Maven\test-output

C:\Users\DYNAMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--1591506395\testng-customsuite.xml

> ```
> [BaseMessageSender] Waiting for Eclipse client on localhost:53913
> [BaseMessageSender] Received a connection from Eclipse on localhost:53913
> [BaseMessageSender] Connection established, starting reader thread
> [BaseMessageSender] ReaderThread waiting for an admin message
> [JsonMessageSender] Sending message [GenericMessage ==> suiteCount:1, testCount:1]
> [BaseMessageSender] ReaderThread received admin message:>ACK
> [BaseMessageSender] Admin message:>ACK
> [BaseMessageSender] Received ACK:>ACK
> [BaseMessageSender] Admin message:>ACK
> [BaseMessageSender] Received ACK:>ACK
> org.testng.TestNGException: 
> Cannot instantiate class com.TectCase.qa.packag.SelectSurveyPageTest
>   at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:30)
>   at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:423)
>   at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:336)
>   at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:125)
>   at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:190)
>   at org.testng.TestClass.getInstances(TestClass.java:95)
>   at org.testng.TestClass.initTestClassesAndInstances(TestClass.java:81)
>   at org.testng.TestClass.init(TestClass.java:73)
>   at org.testng.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:38)
>   at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:389)
>   at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:271)
>   at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:241)
>   at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:192)
>   at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:33)
>   at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:66)
>   at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:713)
>   at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:260)
>   at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:198)
>   at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1295)
>   at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1273)
>   at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1128)
>   at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
>   at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
>   at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
>   at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
>   at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>   at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:24)
>   ... 25 more
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at com.base.packag.TestBase.<init>(TestBase.java:34)
>   at com.TectCase.qa.packag.SelectSurveyPageTest.<init>(SelectSurveyPageTest.java:26)
>   ... 30 more
> java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
>   at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
>   at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
>   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
>   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
>   at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
>   at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
>   at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
>   at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
>   at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
> ```

Comment: Please use tags as it is supposed to, in addition explain in details your code.

Comment: please check your config file path.